# How is the &nbsp; interpreted in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing some web scraping and the table that I have to scrape is ugly, to say the least.
I want to extract all values in a table row until a   character, however I do now know how it is interpreted and how to set the break condition.

This is an example of a raw table row that I need to scrape when I inspect it in the browser:

```
<tr style="height: 19px;">
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 51px;">8,50</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 52px;">13,30</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 52px;">18,10</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 157px;">22,50</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 52px;">8,20</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 53px;">13,00</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 53px;">17,40</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 53px;">22,20</td>
</tr>
```

And as I said, I do not know how to set a condition such that the for-loop stops at `<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>` and continues at the next table row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about something like:

```for cell in row.find_all('td'):

        if '&npsb' in cell.text:
            break```  - it's not letting me format that properly in the comment and I don't wish to add it as an answer, but if you follow logic like that it should work.

Comment: did not work, but I figured just replacing &nbsp with any string after placing the request and then just conditioning on that string works as well. but than you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

`&nbsp;` is replaced by space (`" "`) when you parse your HTML document. So when you use `str.strip()` or `.get_text(strip=True)` you can check for `""`:

```
html_doc = """<tr style="height: 19px;">
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 51px;">8,50</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 52px;">13,30</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 52px;">18,10</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 157px;">22,50</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 52px;">8,20</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 53px;">13,00</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 53px;">17,40</td>
<td class="xl72" style="height: 19px; width: 53px;">22,20</td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for td in soup.select("td"):
    txt = td.get_text(strip=True)
    if txt == "":
        break
    print(txt)
```

Prints:

```
8,50
13,30
18,10
22,50
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from discarding a cell that only contains `&nbsp;`, you could also explicitly **include** only those cells that match your expectations.

For example:

- Only include cells that follow the pattern D+,D+
  (One or more digits, followed by a comma, followed by one or mor digits)

```py
import re

for cell in row.find_all("td"):
    cell_content = cell.text
    if re.match(r"\d+,\d+", cell_content):
        return cell_content
```

Or more simply:

- Only include cells with at least 2 characters

```py
for cell in row.find_all("td"):
    cell_content = cell.text
    if len(cell_content) >= 2:
        return cell_content
```